# Accessing Local Network with VLC Media Player

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, samba, vlc

Server - Windows 7 64 Home

Remote receiver - Lubuntu 19.04

I am able to stream media from the Windows 7 server to Android and iOS apps over the Local Network with excellent results. However, Lubuntu 19.04 seems to be posing difficulties. I installed samba but still had authentication problems. Not sure what to put down for "Domain." The online tips for samba look pretty complicated.

Any quick, simple tips on how to make this work? I am not asking about streaming individual files one at a time but rather, about how to access the server file system from the remote, choose a file remotely and then stream it.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide.  An example of a command I use to mount is `mount //b122/Buffalo /b122 -o username=guiverc,password=secret,sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777`.   You could add to your file system table `/etc/fstab` to have it automatically mount, but in my case it's for backups so scripts `mount` & `umount` it (where I copied the command from; b122 is an ip address my local DNS server provides)

Comment: This - and the link - have been helpful in increasing my rather limited understanding. I tend to contemplate new stuff as I go about my day and then come back to it. Sometimes in long sessions other times in short bursts. My question for now is what does "Buffalo" stand for?

Comment: In my example, my device is a Buffalo linkstation (or something like that), it's a decade old Japanese made old NAS device. Those old devices didn't easily allow name changes, that'll be my second device (b121-b129 are like devices and i use ip address to tell one from another)

Comment: I just re-installed Windows 7 64 on the same PC. Formerly it was dual booted with WinXP Pro and Lubuntu 19.04. Neither version of Windows will connect thru VLC's mDNS Network Discovery. So I am thinking it is a VLC issue, not an OS issue.